# What does the operator := mean?

Tags: operators, pseudocode

I am looking at pseudocode and one part of it is

```
tentative_g_score := g_score[x] + dist_between(x,y)
```

I want to know what does the operator := mean?

Comment: That's just an assignment afaik. Same as `=` in most languages.

Comment: but in the pseudo code, they also use = so it can't be that

Comment: `=` might be an equality check (`==`).

Comment: Found by searching "Programming colon equals".

Comment: blockdavidson - 1) Assignment is the most likely meaning.  2) If it means something else, we would only be able to tell from the **full** context.  3) pseudocode doesn't need to be consistent!